# Hide back button in navigation bar with hidesBackButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uinavigationbar

I want to hide the back button when transitioning from one view to another. I read the questions regarding this problem and every answer was "use `hidesBackButton`". The problem with this is:

- when I put it in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear the back button arrow hides but the string "Back" doesn't.
- when I put it in viewDidAppear the back button disappears but it visible to the user

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is how you can replicate this problem(or bug?)
Make a new Tabbed application with Swift in Xcode. In the FirstViewController.swift use performSegueWithIdentifier to navigate to the second view controller. In the SecondViewController.swift hide the navigation bar back button using hidesBackButton and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: Seems like your problem is somewhere else. self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES works perfect in viewDidLoad(). So, could you send some code?

Comment: Make a new Tabbed application with Swift in Xcode. In the `FirstViewController.swift` use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to navigate to the second view controller. In the `SecondViewController.swift` hide the navigation bar back button using `hidesBackButton` and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: @zinnuree did you get the same problem as me?

Comment: @zinnuree Same problem here. (On iOS 8.1 in `viewWillAppear:`)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Do we know why `hidesBackButton` does not only hide "<" (but not "< Name")? Is this a feature or a bug? I need to hide "< Name" depending on changing conditions in a hierarchy of view controllers where replacing the left bar button item like this apparently introduces more problems than it solves.

Comment: Not sure. I would use an enum

Comment: You can do it a number of places.

Comment: this also works for me.

`self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

did not work for me neither in ViewDidLoad nor in ViewDidAppear

Comment: An even shorter approach: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()` Together with `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` this works perfectly and hides the Back text as well.

Comment: In swift 4, style should be `.plain` now

Answer (score 60):

To hide the back button with the latest Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be :

    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
Since he wants to hide the back button?

Comment: @JordiSipkens - yes, thank you.  I have edited the answer so that the command *hides* the back button.  Use false to reveal the back button again before closing the view, which should be done when using a navigation controller.

Comment: This will hide everything including the arrow icon "<". How to keep arrow icon?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the code below to hide back button on `UINavigationBar`.

**Swift 3**;

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

Answer (score 14):

this worked for me

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 7):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    var button: UIButton = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "person-icon.jpg"), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)
    button.targetForAction("actioncall", withSender: nil)
    var rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightItem.customView = button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this,This worked for me

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I set it in init(), instead of viewDidLoad. Strange though

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 11(maybe sooner, not sure), you can also untick the box under the attribute inspector tab in the storyboard editor if you're not looking to do it programatically.