# Navigation bar not displayed when running the application (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

In my application i have always passed from one page to another without using the Navigation Controller (so doing the classic follows with  function like this

```
  @IBAction func profileTapped (_ sender: Any) {

self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "goToProfile", sender: self)

}
```

, now I have decided to implement it even if not on the initial viewController but on one of the last pages of the app, i want to be connected to only certain pages; so after i added the NC in the storyboard i obviously came across the nav bar on all the pages that have a link with the controller to which i've associated the NC, but when i run the app the nav bar is not displayed, how come? What other changes i have to do? (To be clear, what i did was just add the navigation controller to the storyboard and associate it with the page i wanted)

Comment: Navigation bar will appear only if the viewController is pushed by another viewController and the parent viewController has a navigation ViewController embedded to it. Make sure your ViewController being pushed and parent VC pushing it has a top bar property in storyboard set to anything other than none

Comment: check in the inital VC if the property ('let bla = navigationController') is nil. if not, just try to change bgcolor or something like that so see if it is on screen

Comment: If your parent VC does not have embedded navigation controller than you can add UINavigationBar as subview to your ViewController as well in that case you will have to add back button and handle IBAction/selector of backButton

Comment: @SandeepBhandari so you suggest me to only add the UINavigationBar without Navigation Controller? Because the first 3 VC of my app do not have a link with the Navigation Controller because i do not want it

Comment: @seran : Yes if that makes sense to your app. Using navigationController does not only mean a navigation bar and a fancy animation. It means much more. Navigation Controller provides a stack which will hold the instances of all VCs pushed on to it till it gets popped out. If your app does not provide any mechanism to go back from VC3 to VC1 then you dont need NavigationController set as initialViewController or embed it in VC1. If only VC4 needs to have backButton and you can add navBar and add custom backButton and add selector to handle backButton tap pop the VC4 iOS will take you to VC

Comment: loaded VC4 behaving like back button. If in case you are concerned about animation you can provide custom animations to segue there by creating a illusion as if UIViewController being popped from stack though its merely being dismissed

Comment: @SandeepBhandari ok thank you for the answer, one last question, if i decide to add the Navigation Controller at my first VC so i'll have all the pages with the nav bar, is possibile to delete some back buttons to the pages do not need?

Comment: You can. In each viewController where you don't want navigation bar to appear you can hide navigation bar by calling `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` And if you are planning to hide only backButton you can say @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091015/hide-back-button-in-navigation-bar-with-hidesbackbutton-in-swift

Comment: @SandeepBhandari oh perfect, really thank you!